# Plain text email sent via JavaMail arrives as an attachment

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, plaintext

I have written a code to send via java mail API.Everything is working fine but the plain text which I am sending in received by recipient in form of downloadable attachment rather than plain text message.

I don't know why this is happening.
Given below is the code and its output when I run it.

```
        String toEmail=request.getParameter("email");
        String subject=request.getParameter("subject");
        String message=request.getParameter("message");

        String fromEmail="suyash.tilhari12@gmail.com";
        String username="suyash.tilhari12";
        String password="********";

        mailSender.sendEmail(fromEmail, username, password, toEmail, subject, message);
```

```
   public void sendEmail(String fromEmail,String username,String password,
            String toEmail,String subject,String  message) 
    {
        try
        {
        Properties props= System.getProperties();
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false");

        Session mailSession = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);
        mailSession.setDebug(true);

        Message mailMessage=new MimeMessage(mailSession);
        mailMessage.setFrom(new InternetAddress(fromEmail));
        mailMessage.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(toEmail));
        mailMessage.setContent(message, "html/text");
        mailMessage.setSubject(subject);

        Transport transport=mailSession.getTransport("smtp");
        transport.connect("smtp.gmail.com",username,password);
        transport.sendMessage(mailMessage, mailMessage.getAllRecipients());
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(MailSenderBean.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

}
```

I have used Java Mail API ,NetBeans IDE ,Glassfish Server,Enterprise JAVA Bean.

**THE RESULT IS AS FOLLOWS:**

**Mail recipient-
Look,the simple text message is in form of attachment.**

[image]

**The message is inside this attachment which is now downloaded and opened-**

[image]

How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Suyash: Try following instructions on this http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_sending_email.htm link.

Comment: Thanks I visited this tutorial and found that I need to write      mailMessage.setText(message);    instead of -->  mailMessage.setContent(message, "html/text");   and this worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the content as `"text/html"` and not as `"html/text"`

So it should look like :

```
 setContent(message, "text/html" );
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem in your case is related to MIME content. Everything is correct, but not that part.

In that line

```
mailMessage.setContent(message, "html/text");
```

You are using "html/text" as mime type, which is not valid.

You can find a list of MIME types here:
http://www.sitepoint.com/web-foundations/mime-types-complete-list/

The code should be

```
mailMessage.setContent(message, "text/plain");
```

or

```
mailMessage.setContent(message, "text/plain; charset=UTF-8");
```

to include charset information (ISO-8859-1, UTF-8, etc.).

This is the case for sending only one content. If you need to send content in different formats (for example html and plain text) or you need to send attachments, you have to use MimeMultipart

Comment: Or use the [`setText`](https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/javax/mail/internet/MimeMessage.html#setText-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) method.  And fix these [common mistakes](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#commonmistakes).

Comment: You are right, using setText solves this problem, and it's easier in this case. I was just trying to explain why it wasn't working.